# Creating user without password with doorkeeper oauth2 provider throught provider like Google, Github, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, doorkeeper

I created api app, which is oauth2 provider, with ruby on rails and doorkeeper. The goal is to create user without password, just with using some oauth2 provider (Google, GitHub, LinkedIn, ...).

But I have a problem, when new user comes into my app he is just saved into DB but not authorized. However, when he comes second time he is authorized without any problem.

Here is Doorkeeper configuration and I don't know how set it to return user after redirecting and creating new user.

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to('/auth/some_provider')
  end
  skip_authorization do
    true
  end
end
```